# Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: Only works on Chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-9, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm developing an ASP.NET website that connects to Oracle Database and bind some data to gridview. Everything's fine until here; however when I decided to add Ajax Control Toolkit to my project in order to use "Calendar Extender" and "Timer", website crashes both on IE9 and Firefox. And the most awkward part is that it works on Chrome perfectly! I already disabled debugging on the explorer to see if it works but it's not. I don't seem to come up with a solution since I tell people to go the site only on Chrome. I'm working on VS2008 and .NET 3.5 also using AJAXcontroltoolkit 3.5. I can link you the picture of error if it helps. Any help would be highly appreciated...!

---

Here's my default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Scheduler Job Dependency</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 679px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 679px;
            text-align: right;
            height: 26px;
        }
        .style4
        {
            height: 26px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="150px" 
            ToolTip="DWM">
            <img alt="DWM" src="dwm_web_logo_s.jpg"
                style="width: 1024px; height: 150px"; title="DWM" />
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="49px" style="margin-top: 21px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Scheduler İş Bağımlılıkları" 
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
            ForeColor="#2A0A93"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2" style="text-align: right">
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"  ToolTip="Job'ın Bulunduğu Plan Adı"
                        Text="PLAN_NAME:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="Plan Adını Girin:" 
                        AutoCompleteType="Cellular"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"  ToolTip="Job'a Verilen Ad"
                        Text="JOB_NAME:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left" class="style4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ToolTip="Job Adını Girin:"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"  ToolTip="Job Başlangıç Tarihi" 
                        Text="ETT_DATE:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" 
                        ToolTip="Job Başlangıç Tarihini Seçin:">
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox3" runat="server" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Height="85px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        Width="1129px">

        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Height="83px" 
            RepeatLayout="Flow" Width="410px">
            <asp:ListItem>Job&#39;a bağımlı olan çalışan/çalışmaya hazır işler</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Job&#39;a bağımlı olan, bağımlılığı tamamlanmamış işler</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Job&#39;a bağımlı, tamamlanmış işler</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Job&#39;a bağımlı tüm işler</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <p style="margin-left: 600px">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
        <br />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel12" runat="server" Height="30px">
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Tamam" 
            Width="71px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Height="25px" onclick="btnTest_Click" 
            style="width: 39px" Text="Test" Width="68px" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <div>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
           <%-- UpdateMode for Update Panel is set Conditional as it will update it's content based upon condition  --%>
         <Triggers><%-- Triggers contains the list of events that will force update panel to update it's content asynchronously--%>
              <%-- Tick event of timer1 has been selected as Triggering event for asynchronous updation of update panel data which will be executed at each time-interval(10 seconds) specified --%>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
          </Triggers> 
         <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridJobs" runat="server" Height="16px" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="77px">
                <RowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="X-Small" BorderColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2A0A93" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Groove" 
                    Font-Names="Gisha" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="Small" />
            </asp:GridView>
             <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" 
                 EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true">
             </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
             <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="600000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
             </asp:Timer>
        </ContentTemplate>        
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </div>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include a short example that repeats the problem?  Also, do you have a `ScriptManager` or `ToolkitScriptManager` on the page?

Comment: Yes, I have a ToolKitScriptManager on the page. Some people referred me to use just ScriptManager instead of it but it didn't work either... I use the calendar extender with a textbox and timer for updating the gridview...

Comment: Good to know.  Please copy / paste a **short** example that repeats the problem **into your question**.  That way we can try out the code and try to see where the problem is =)

Comment: ok, sorry for the late respond; is my default.aspx page is enough which includes ajax tools?

Comment: No problem.  Yes, that should be plenty.